# Linux tr command

Tags: command, tr

I'm stuck and hope someone can help. I am trying to use the ***tr*** command to capitalize the text of first two columns of a file but can't seem to figure it out. It's actually for an assignment for a class I am taking and I must use ***tr***. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tr-command-in-unix-linux-with-examples/

Answer (score 3):

This is a comprehensive guide/explanation to using **tr**

**Reference:** http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/12/linux-tr-command/

The general syntax of **tr** is

```
 tr [options] set1 [set2]
```

The items in the square brackets are optional. tr requires at least one argument and accepts a maximum of two. The first, designated **set1**, lists the characters in the text to be replaced or removed. The second, **set2**, lists the characters that are to be substituted for the characters listed in the first argument.